# .htaccess redirection to directories depends on URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, directory

1) I have such directory structure:

```
.htaccess
album/
    index.php
web/
    .htaccess
     index.php
    ...
...
```

In 'album' there is a gallery page and in 'web' there is a WordPress page.
How to fill .htaccess (I suppose in root dir) to redirect addresses depends on what is in URL:

```
www.domain.org         -> goto /web and display wordpress page
www.domain.org/album   -> goto /album and display gallery page
```

I've tried such thing in root .htaccess but without success (there is constant redirection to domain.org/web):

```
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.org$ [NC]
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ /web
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.org/album$ [NC]
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ /album [L]
```

.htaccess in web directory is default of WordPress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

How to solve this riddle?

Regards.

------------------
One of possible answer to  thequestion (

```
RewriteEngine On

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.org$ [NC]
ReWriteRule ^album(.*)$ album$1 [L]

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.org$ [NC]
ReWriteRule  web/$1 [L]
```

Weard is last line of this code. There are two spaces. I suppose first space means "empty string". This is strange (and also bad coding) however it works and I have enough of those redirections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.org$ [NC]
ReWriteRule ^((?!album).*)$ web/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has guided me for proper solution (look into question).

Comment: Sorry but what you've posted in question is not proper as `ReWriteRule ^album(.*)$ album$1 [L]` is not doing anything but rewriting `album` to `album`

Comment: I am no expert with this but somehow this is only working solution (I've tried many possibilities including your one). Maybe this is matter of provider. Remember if index.php is present in the directory it is called automatically. Additionally I suppose your version redirect every "album/../..." to "album/index.php", also inner-admin page. Honestly, despite I am developer those .htaccess rules are extremaly unintuitive for me.

Comment: This pattern `^album(.*)$` in your rule will also match every URI that starts with `album`. Try my shortened updated code.

Comment: Yes, now it solves the problem. Just FYI it has some side effect. Everything in domain except "album" is redirected to "web". But this is no clue of this problem. I assumed that album$1 [L] should copy part of address after "album" to the end and I used it rather as a "brake" command (I hope).